# Parsing callbacks in GSON

Tags: android, json, parsing, gson

Is there any way I can get notified once parsing of certain object is finished, so I can validate/process parsed data.
I'm using [SimpleXML](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php) to parse my XMLs and they have `@Validate` and `@Commit` annotations, so I can specify function which should be triggered whenever parsing process is done.
Couldn't find anything similar for GSON though. Is there anybody out there who had the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gson is synchronous and does not create any threads. The deserialized object or serialized JSON is returned to you from the respective method calls. It does not offer the functionality you're looking for.